# Trying to view a PDF in "kiosk mode"

Tags: pdf

I have built an interactive PDF for a client using Adobe Acrobat and I am just preparing it to be sent to them, when I view it in regular view or full screen all the buttons work fine that I have made and the content looks fine, however when you tap on anything that isn't one of the interactive buttons that I created (which is the majority of the page), it exits full-screen view.

This is extremely problematic for me as this will be used by customers at a stand and so needs to remain in full-screen view the whole time for them to use as in it's current state the user can tap once on the screen and exit the PDF which gives them access to the computer etc.

Do you know if there is either a way to enable a kind of 'kiosk mode' on the PDF or is there another tool that will allow me to do this?

Comment: This site is for questions about _using_ web applications, not _developing_ them.

Comment: Yes and you will notice that my question is about "using" the software, not "developing" it...

Comment: If "the software" in question is Adobe Acrobat, it is a desktop software application, so it will still be off-topic. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I created the PDF using Adobe Acrobat however I am asking in general if there is a way to do this, perhaps using a web application...?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/88163)

Comment: @James: Nobody is intentionally ganging up on you, but I agree with Vidar and Rubén that your question would fit better elsewhere, particularly Super User. A web application requires some kind of web browser to run, so it would be the browser itself that would open in kiosk mode, not the webapp; questions about browsers are off-topic on this site, hence the comments and downvotes your question has received. The folks on Super User would be more than happy to help you out with this, however. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your own javascript to disable this feature:

```
app.fs.isFullScreen = true;
app.fs.clickAdvances = false;
```